Reassign order after count function
I want to count the Employee where Remarks is Yes
I have this DF1:



Employeed_ID
Remarks
count_row




1211
Yes
3


1211
No
3


1211
Yes
3


1212
Yes
4


1212
No
4


1212
Yes
4


1212
Yes
4


1213
No
2


1213
Yes
2



my expected df:
the count_row_yes values count the employee where Remarks is Yes and count_row_asc counting the column count_row_yes ascending/increasingly.



Employeed_ID
Remarks
count_row
count_row_yes
count_row_asc




1211
Yes
3
2
1


1211
Yes
3
2
2


1212
Yes
4
3
1


1212
Yes
4
3
2


1212
Yes
4
3
3


1213
Yes
2
1
1



res = df1.groupBy("Employeed_ID").agg(count(when(col("Remarks") == "Yes", True)).alias("count_row_yes"))

I want to achieve the column count_row_asc.


keep only rows where Remarks is "Yes"

The window specification ensures that the operations like counting are done for each Employeed_ID.

Next take cumulative count for how many times "Yes" appears for each employee.

Finally row number that increments every time "Yes" appears for each employee
df_yes = df1.filter(F.col('Remarks') == 'Yes') #(Filters Yes)

window_spec = Window.partitionBy('Employeed_ID').orderBy('Employeed_ID')

df_yes = df_yes.withColumn('count_row_yes', F.count('Remarks').over(window_spec))

df_yes = df_yes.withColumn('count_row_asc', F.row_number().over(window_spec))
df_yes.display()





got my expected result. thanks for this @prathik
